# How to select tables with specific degree from user_tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
select * from user_tables where degree = '1';
```

this is giving null but when we do

```
select * from user_tables
```

then it does show tables with 1 degree

Comment: What is the data type of column  `degree`?  if it is VARCHAR2 it may contain spaces you can't see in the output e.g. `'1 '`

Comment: I missed it,  usually I do trim the character,
it worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue few years back, Degree column is varchar2(10) and hence you should use below query

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TRIM(DEGREE) = '6';
```